C definition class
`I need help with IPropertyChanged, how to do it so it works.
`C# how to create object class using IPropertyChanged ?
I tried to do it inside of my class, but its not working, I need to somehow change it or add some methods. I'm trying to implement the INotifyPropertyChanged interface in my Employee class, but I'm having trouble making it work. I need to ensure that property changes are correctly notified. Below are the details of my implementation:
Employee Class:
This class represents an employee with properties such as Name, Position, Phone, etc.
I've implemented INotifyPropertyChanged to notify changes in these properties. 
    public string? Name { get; set; }
    public string? Position { get; set; }
    public string? Phone { get; set; }
    public string? Email { get; set; }
    public string? Room { get; set; }
    public string? MainWorkplace { get; set; }
    public string? Workplace { get; set; }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler? PropertyChanged;

Here is how it works, maybe i forgot to put some brackets. There are 3 classes, each represents some object, i need to apply inotifychanged to it EmployeeList Class: This class represents a collection of employees and provides methods to load from and save to a JSON file. It also includes methods to search employees and get distinct positions and workplaces.
public class EmployeeList : ObservableCollection<Employee>
{
    public static EmployeeList? LoadFromJson(FileInfo jsonFile)
    {
        if (!jsonFile.Exists)
            throw new FileNotFoundException("Súbor typu JSON neexistuje !", jsonFile.FullName);

        string jsonText = File.ReadAllText(jsonFile.FullName);
        EmployeeList? employeeList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<EmployeeList>(jsonText);

        return employeeList;
    }

    `public void SaveToJson(FileInfo jsonFile)
    {
        string jsonText = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(this, Formatting.Indented);
        File.WriteAllText(jsonFile.FullName, jsonText);
    }
    public IEnumerable<string?> GetPositions() => this.Select(employee => employee.Position).Distinct().OrderBy(p => p);
    public IEnumerable<string?> GetMainWorkplaces() => this.Select(employee => employee.MainWorkplace).Distinct().OrderBy(wp => wp);

    public SearchResult Search(string? name, string? position, string? mainWorkplace)
    {
        IEnumerable<Employee> emps = this.AsEnumerable();
        List<Employee> filteredEmps = new();

        foreach (var e in emps)
        {
            bool matchOfMW = true;
            bool matchOfP = true;
            bool matchOfN = true;

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(mainWorkplace))
                matchOfMW = e.MainWorkplace?.IndexOf(mainWorkplace, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0;

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(position))
                matchOfP = e.Position?.IndexOf(position, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0;

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(name))
                matchOfN = e.Name?.IndexOf(name, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0;

            if (matchOfMW && matchOfP && matchOfN)
                filteredEmps.Add(e);
        }

        Console.WriteLine($"Počet ľudí: {emps.Count()}");
        Console.WriteLine($"Z toho spĺňajúci: {filteredEmps.Count} \n");
        return new SearchResult(filteredEmps.ToArray());
    }
}`

`public class SearchResult
{
    public Employee[] Employees { get; }

    public SearchResult(Employee[] employees)
    {
        Employees = employees;
    }
    public void SaveToCsvFile(string filePath, string delimiter = "\t")
    {
        if (Employees == null)
            return;

        using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(filePath, false, Encoding.UTF8))
        {
            writer.Write("\uFEFF");
            writer.WriteLine($"Name{delimiter}Position{delimiter}Phone{delimiter}Email{delimiter}Room{delimiter}MainWorkplace{delimiter}Workplace");
            foreach (Employee e in Employees)
            {
                writer.WriteLine($"{e.Name}{delimiter}{e.Position}{delimiter}{e.Phone}{delimiter}{e.Email}" + $"{delimiter}{e.Room}{delimiter}{e.MainWorkplace}{delimiter}{e.Workplace}");
            }
        }

    }
    public int GetEmployeeCount()
    {
        return Employees.Length;
    }`

Here is how it works, maybe i forgot to put some brackets. There are 3 classes, each represents some object, i need to apply inotifychanged to it.

The most simply way to implement INotifyPropertyChanged today is to use CommunityToolkit.Mvvm. Derive your view model class from ObservableObject and declare only the backing fields of observable properties with the [ObservableProperty] attribute. The associated properties will be generated automatically.

Your question is a little bit confusing. Do you ask how to implement INotifyPropertyChanged? Or do you ask how to let the EmployeeList raise a change event when its items have changed? What exactly is the question or what does "i need to apply inotifychanged to it" means?

I would do it like this
public class Employee : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _name = string.Empty;
    private string _position = string.Empty;
    private string? _mainWorkplace;
    private string _email = string.Empty;
    private string? _room;
    private string? _phone;
    private string? _workplace;

    public string Name { get => _name;
        set
        {
            if (_name != value)
            {
                _name = value;
                PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(Name));
            }
        }
    }
    public string Position { get => _position;
        set
        {
            if (_position != value)
            {
                _position = value;
                PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(Position));
            }
        }
    }
    public string? Phone { get => _phone;
        set
        {
            if (_phone != value)
            {
                _phone = value;
                PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(Phone));
            }
        }
    }

    public string Email { get => _email;
        set
        {
            if (_email != value)
            {
                _email = value;
                PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(Email));
            }
        }
    }

    public string? Room { get => _room;
        set
        {
            if (_room != value)
            {
                _room = value;
                PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(Room));
            }
        }
    }

    public string? MainWorkplace { get => _mainWorkplace;
        set
        {
            if (_mainWorkplace != value)
            {
                _mainWorkplace = value;
                PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(MainWorkplace));
            }
        }
    }

    public string? Workplace { get => _workplace; 
        set { 
            if (_workplace != value) { 
                _workplace = value;
                PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(Workplace));
            }
        }
        
    }






    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler? PropertyChanged;



}

}
)
public class EmployeeList : ObservableCollection<Employee>
{
    public static EmployeeList? LoadFromJson(FileInfo jsonFile) {
        try
        {
            if (jsonFile.Exists)
            {
                var json = File.ReadAllText(jsonFile.FullName);
                var employeeList = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<EmployeeList>(json);
                return employeeList ?? new EmployeeList(); 
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Error loading JSON file: {ex.Message}");
        }

        return new EmployeeList();
    }

    public void SaveToJson(FileInfo jsonFile)
    {
        try
        {
            if(jsonFile.Exists)
            {
                var json = JsonSerializer.Serialize(this);
                File.WriteAllText(jsonFile.FullName, json);
            } 
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Error saving to JSON file: {ex.Message}");
        }
    } 

    public IEnumerable<string> GetPositions(FileInfo jsonFile)
    {
        return this.Select(e => e.Position).Distinct().OrderBy(p => p);
        
    }
    public IEnumerable<string> GetMainWorkplace(FileInfo jsonFile)
    {
        return this.Select(e => e.MainWorkplace).Distinct().OrderBy(mw => mw);

    }


    public SearchResult Search(string? mainWorkplace = null, string? position = null, string? name = null)
    {

       var results = this.Where(e =>

            (string.IsNullOrEmpty(mainWorkplace) || e.MainWorkplace.Equals(mainWorkplace, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)) &&

            (string.IsNullOrEmpty(position) || e.Position.Equals(position, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)) &&

            (string.IsNullOrEmpty(name) || e.Name.Contains(name, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        ).ToList();

        return new SearchResult(results);
    }




}

}
public class SearchResult
{

    public List<Employee> Employees { get; }

    public SearchResult(List<Employee> employees) 
    {
        Employees = employees ?? new List<Employee>(); 
    }


    public void SaveToCsv(FileInfo csvFile, string delimiter = "\t")
    {
        try
        {

            var lines = new List<string>
            {
                "Name,Position,Phone,Email,Room,MainWorkplace,Workplace"
            };

            lines.AddRange(Employees.Select(e => $"{e.Name}{delimiter}{e.Position}{delimiter}{e.Phone}{delimiter}{e.Email}{delimiter}{e.Room}{delimiter}{e.MainWorkplace}{delimiter}{e.Workplace}"));

            File.WriteAllLines(csvFile.FullName, lines);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
        }


        }

}

}
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string? inputFile = null;
        string? name = null;
        string? position = null;
        string? mainWorkplace = null;
        string? outputFile = null;

        // Parsovanie argumentov z prikazoveho riadku
        for (int i = 0; i < args.Length; i++)
        {
            switch (args[i])
            {
                case "--input":
                    inputFile = args[++i];
                    break;
                case "--name":
                    name = args[++i];
                    break;
                case "--position":
                    position = args[++i];
                    break;
                case "--main-workplace":
                    mainWorkplace = args[++i];
                    break;
                case "--output":
                    outputFile = args[++i];
                    break;
            }
        }

        // Validacia argumentu pre vstupny subor
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(inputFile) || !File.Exists(inputFile))
        {
            Console.Error.WriteLine("Invalid or missing input file.");
            return;
        }

        var inputFileInfo = new FileInfo(inputFile);
        var employeeList = EmployeeList.LoadFromJson(inputFileInfo);

        // vyhladavanie
        var searchResult = employeeList.Search(mainWorkplace, position, name);

        // Vypis do konzoly
        for (int i = 0; i < searchResult.Employees.Count; i++)
        {
            var employee = searchResult.Employees[i];
            Console.WriteLine($"[{i + 1}] {employee.Name}");
            Console.WriteLine($"Pracovisko: {employee.Workplace}");
            Console.WriteLine($"Miestnost: {employee.Room}");
            Console.WriteLine($"Telefon: {employee.Phone}");
            Console.WriteLine($"E-mail: {employee.Email}");
            Console.WriteLine($"Funkcia: {employee.Position}");
            Console.WriteLine();
        }

        // Ulozenie CSV ak je outputFile
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(outputFile))
        {
            var outputFileInfo = new FileInfo(outputFile);
            searchResult.SaveToCsv(outputFileInfo);
            Console.WriteLine($"Search results saved to {outputFile}");
        }
    }
}

}
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private EmployeeList _employeeList = new EmployeeList(); 

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void BtnLoad_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        OpenFileDialog openFileDialog = new()
        {
            Filter = "JSON files (*.json)|*.json|All files (*.*)|*.*" // Nastavenie filtra pre OpenFileDialog
        };

        // Kontrola, či užívateľ vybral súbor
        if (openFileDialog.ShowDialog() == true)
        {
            var fileInfo = new FileInfo(openFileDialog.FileName);
            _employeeList = EmployeeList.LoadFromJson(fileInfo) ?? new EmployeeList(); 
            if (_employeeList.Count > 0)
            {
                PopulateComboBoxes(); // Naplnenie ComboBoxov udajmi
                MessageBox.Show("Employees loaded successfully!"); 
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Failed to load employees or the list is empty."); 
            }
        }
    }

    private void PopulateComboBoxes()
    {
        cbPosition.Items.Clear();
        cbMainWorkplace.Items.Clear();

        
        cbPosition.Items.Add(string.Empty);
        cbMainWorkplace.Items.Add(string.Empty);

        // ComboBox pozicie
        foreach (var position in _employeeList.GetPositions())
        {
            cbPosition.Items.Add(position);
        }

        // ComboBox hlavne pracoviska
        foreach (var workplace in _employeeList.GetMainWorkplaces())
        {
            cbMainWorkplace.Items.Add(workplace);
        }

        
        cbPosition.SelectedIndex = 0;
        cbMainWorkplace.SelectedIndex = 0;
    }

    private void BtnSearch_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Ziskanie hodnot 
        string? name = string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtName.Text) ? null : txtName.Text;
        string? position = cbPosition.SelectedItem as string;
        string? mainWorkplace = cbMainWorkplace.SelectedItem as string;

       
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(position)) position = null;
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(mainWorkplace)) mainWorkplace = null;

        
        var searchResult = _employeeList.Search(mainWorkplace, position, name);

       
        lvEmployees.ItemsSource = searchResult.Employees;
        txtEmployeeCount.Text = searchResult.Employees.Count.ToString();
    }

    private void BtnReset_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        
        txtName.Clear();
        cbPosition.SelectedIndex = 0;
        cbMainWorkplace.SelectedIndex = 0;
        lvEmployees.ItemsSource = null; 
        txtEmployeeCount.Text = "0"; 
    }

    private void BtnExport_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        SaveFileDialog saveFileDialog = new()
        {
            Filter = "CSV files (*.csv)|*.csv|All files (*.*)|*.*" 
        };

        
        if (saveFileDialog.ShowDialog() == true)
        {
            var fileInfo = new FileInfo(saveFileDialog.FileName);
            var employees = lvEmployees.ItemsSource as List<Employee> ?? new List<Employee>(); 
            var searchResult = new SearchResult(employees);
            searchResult.SaveToCsv(fileInfo); 
            MessageBox.Show("Search results exported to CSV successfully!"); 
        }
    }
}

}

Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. Would you kindly edit your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?
